# Changing the previous element at the same level if it's a string without nuking the whole parent

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a mixed list of strings and span elements. I want to remove the span elements but first, I want to modify the string preceding each span element if it exists (a regex can take care of that part.) Some br elements can come in the middle.

```
<li>
foo
<span class='x'> ... </span>
<span class='y'> ... </span>
<br>
bar
<span class='z'> ... </span>
</li>
```

Desired result:

`foo\nbar`

I know how to substitute the br tag for a text string. No problemo. It's changing the segment of the string that just precede (or added bonus, follow) the span element, I am struggling to do.

I tried to use `previous_sibling` and `previous_element`. But when I change the parent.string, the whole list is replaced (of course!).

How can I change the previous string element in the tree before removing each span. There doesn't seem to be a way to just change the previous element if it's a string.

Iterating thru the contents could work by testing for NavigableString and Tag elements but this seems rather tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood you well, but if you want only find text elements inside `<li>` tag and not inside `<span>`s, you can do `.find_all` with `text=True` and `recursive=False`:

```py
for t in soup.li.find_all(text=True, recursive=False):
    if not t.strip():
        continue
    t.replace_with("XXX")  # <-- change the text inside `<li>` only


print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```html
<li>
 XXX
 <span class="x">
  ...
 </span>
 <span class="y">
  ...
 </span>
 <br/>
 XXX
 <span class="z">
  ...
 </span>
</li>
```

Comment: But then how do I determine if the span element is following the text element if I set recursive to `False`?

Comment: @JohnDifool Maybe with `.find_next`/`.find_previous` ?